# Como fazer pesquisar de data através do dateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datepicker

Como fazer pesquisar através de um `dateTimePicker` (com evento ValueChanged) datas inseridas numa Data Grid View?

Quando carregasse no ano queria que aparecessem todos os registos daquele ano, depois carregar no mês e aparecer todos os registos daquele ano naquele mês e depois carregar no dia para aparecer todos os registos daquele ano, daquele mês, daquele dia.

Não estou a conseguir que isso aconteça.

[image]

```
    private void dateTimePicker_pesquisar_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ano = dateTimePicker_pesquisar.Value.Year;
        int mes = dateTimePicker_pesquisar.Value.Month;
        int dia = dateTimePicker_pesquisar.Value.Day;

        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();

        sqlCommand.CommandText = ("select * from Hora WHERE data like '" + ano + "%'");

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dataGridView_Principal.DataSource = dataTable;

        SomarTotalGrid();

        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Amigo pelo que entendi, você quer carregar primeiro o ano, ai mostraria tudo que fosse daquele ano, depois o mês ao mostraria tudo daquele mês e assim para o dia certo? como você esta definindo os parametros de busca? em um único datatimepiker? acho que voce vai ter que ter um para o ano um para o mes e um para o dia.

Comment: Sim @Thomas Erich Pimentel é num date time piker... queria fazer tudo num só para não ficar com muita coisa.

Comment: então, ate da pra extrair os meses ou dias de um so, porem vc teria que ter 3 botoes, para buscar ou pelo ano ou pelo mes ou pelo dia. pq se não como vo definiria para o sistema quando é para buscar pelo dia, ou quando é para buscar pelo mes por exemplo.

Comment: @Thomas Erich Pimentel acho que se houvesse forma de saber que botão foi clicado no date time piker conseguia fazer... mas achar essa forma também não está fácil

Comment: é talvez seja possível, espera que jaja alguem respode ai.

Answer (score 1):

Caso você user seu componente `dateTimePicker_pesquisar` para filtra os dados pelo *ano mês e dia* passando um a um separadamente você pode fazer conforme o exemplo abaixo.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sqlConnection.ConnectionString =
            "Data Source=DESK008;" +
            "Initial Catalog=stackoverflow;" +
            "User id=sa;" +
            "Password=123456;";
        }

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ano = dateTimePicker_pesquisar.Value.Year;
            int mes = dateTimePicker_pesquisar.Value.Month;
            int dia = dateTimePicker_pesquisar.Value.Day;

            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();

            sqlCommand.CommandText = ("select * from Hora WHERE  year(data) = @ano and month(data) = @mes and day(data) = @dia ");

            // Adicione o parâmetro de entrada e definar suas propriedades .
            SqlParameter parameterAno = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@ano",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = ano
            };

            SqlParameter parameterMes = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@mes",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = mes
            };

            SqlParameter parameterDia = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@dia",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = dia
            };

            // Adicione o parâmetro para a coleção Parameters. 
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterAno);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterMes);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterDia);

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


            dataGridView_Principal.DataSource = dataTable;

            //SomarTotalGrid();

            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Ou você pode resumir sua `query` em um único parâmetro.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = dateTimePicker_pesquisar.Value.Date;

    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();

    sqlCommand.CommandText = ("select * from Hora WHERE  convert(date, data) = @data ");

    // Adicione o parâmetro de entrada e definar suas propriedades .
    SqlParameter parameterdata = new SqlParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "@data",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        Value = data
    };

    // Adicione o parâmetro para a coleção Parameters. 
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterdata);

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    dataGridView_Principal.DataSource = dataTable;

    //SomarTotalGrid();

    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Ou caso o usuário for digita o ano mês e dia em campos separadamente você pode usar a primeira opção só altera o tipo de entrada no form e capturar no *code behind.*

Ou ainda implementando seu evento `picker_ValueChanged`. usando o [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sqlConnection.ConnectionString =
            "Data Source=DESK008;" +
            "Initial Catalog=stackoverflow;" +
            "User id=sa;" +
            "Password=123456;";

            dateTimePicker_pesquisar.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        }

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var data = dateTimePicker_pesquisar.Value.Date;

            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();

            sqlCommand.CommandText = ("select * from Hora WHERE  convert(date, data) = @data ");

            // Adicione o parâmetro de entrada e definar suas propriedades .
            SqlParameter parameterdata = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@data",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = data
            };

            // Adicione o parâmetro para a coleção Parameters. 
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterdata);

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            dataGridView_Principal.DataSource = dataTable;

            //SomarTotalGrid();

            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho que a opção mais indicada para mim seria a 1ª, mas não consigo fazer com que pesquise separadamente. Por exemplo hoje é dia 07-09-2016 o que quer dizer que o "int ano = 2016, int mes = 09 e int dia = 07".

Comment: Você não precisa passar o ano mês e dia separadamente.  Porque sua data do banco é do tipo date.  E quando você alterar a data no seu componente ele passa a data completa seria necessário apenas comprará como no último exemplo

Comment: Acho que a opção mais indicada para mim seria a 1ª, mas não consigo fazer com que pesquise separadamente. Por exemplo hoje é dia 07-09-2016 o que quer dizer que o "int ano = 2016, int mes = 09 e int dia = 07".
Por exemplo, tenho duas datas '2015-09-07' e outra '2015-05-04' e quando carrego no dateTimePiker e selecciono 2015 queria que aparecesse tudo de 2015, mas o que acontece é que só vai aparecer um registo '2015-09-07' porque tenho um ""select * from Hora WHERE  year(data) = @ano-(2015)  and month(data) = @mes-(09) and day(data) = @dia-(07) ""...  @GOKU SSJ4

Comment: Você não vai conseguir fazer dessa forma, porque não tem como sabe qual foi o valor alterado no seu controle dateTimePicker, a não ser que você crie uma variável com o valor anterior ao acionar o evento, após isso você teria que separa seu select em uma string e ir concatenando de acordo com as variáveis que você esta alterado.

Comment: A única vez que consegui foi guardando em variáveis e ia fazendo verificações, mas mesmo assim dava algumas falhas! Obrigado pela sua ajuda @GOKU SSJ4, deu-me muita informação útil.

Comment: Sempre use SqlParameter para passar parâmetros na sua query

Comment: @DiogoSousa, Você teria que substituir seu controle dateTimePicker em campos Ano , mês e dia para ser informado separado ai seria possível você fazer o select dessa forma.